# Problem using mysql joins

Tags: mysql, join

I'm fairly new to mysql and I have no idea if I'm heading in the right direction but I'm having trouble with a mysql query.

I basically have a table of users

```
id      name  
----    -------- 
1       user1          
2       user2          
3       user3          
4       user4
```

as well as a table of user attributes

```
id      userid   attribute 
----    -----    ------ 
1       1        5          
2       1        6       
3       2        5          
4       3        4
```

I want to be able to select users that have both the attribute 5 and the attribute 6, so in this case I want to return

```
id      name  
----    -------- 
1       user1
```

I tried using a join like this.

```
SELECT u.id, u.name FROM users u LEFT JOIN attributes a ON (a.userid = u.id) WHERE a.attribute = 5 AND a.attribute = 6
```

But obviously that won't work, what is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 4):

One way to do this would be to use two joins; eg:

```
SELECT ...
FROM users u
    JOIN attributes a5 ON u.id = a5.userid AND a5.attribute = 5
    JOIN attributes a6 ON u.id = a6.userid AND a6.attribute = 6
```

Another way is by grouping (note that I am a MS SQL person, not sure if this is the right syntax for mysql or not):

```
SELECT u.id, u.name
FROM users u
    JOIN attributes a ON u.id = a.userid
WHERE a.attribute IN (5,6)
GROUP BY u.id, u.name
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Comment: Very nice.  I like the grouping solution.  I was sure there had to be a better way than having to have a join for every required attribute.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.id, u.name FROM users u
  INNER JOIN attributes a1 ON u.id = a1.userid
  INNER JOIN attributes a2 ON u.id = a2.userid
WHERE a1.attribute = 5 AND a2.attribute = 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the query like this would work:

***Select all from attributes table that equals 5 or 6 and then check the users who match.***

```
SELECT a.id, u.name
FROM attributes AS a
LEFT JOIN users AS u ON a.id = u.id
WHERE a.attribute = 5 OR a.attribute = 6
```

Comment: @Frankie: funny how everyone except you haven't noticed such simple mistake :)

Comment: @Alexander: I guess the question is very leaned towards the 'users' table and people start thinking about that one right away as the first query. Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, I don't think the other two current answers are satisfactory.

If you want to:

> select users that have **both** the
>   attribute 5 and the attribute 6

The following query is one way to accomplish that:

```
select
  *
from
  users
where
  id in (select userid from attributes where attribute = 5)
  and
  id in (select userid from attributes where attribute = 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I am not much into SQL, maybe GROUP BY and HAVING will help you:)
Check out the reference: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp